# how to stop Bootstrap-3-Typeahead dropdown displaying the elements in the sorted order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sorting

I'm using [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

Is there a way to avoid the dropdown data getting sorted in natural order ?

This will show all the data in the source in the drop down list in the onFocus event. So the problem is it will only show limited number of elements with the natural sorted order though I don't want them to be.

How can I avoid them getting sorted.

```
$('#device').tagsinput({
      typeahead: {
        source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo','Amstedrdam', 'Washidngton', 'Syddney', 'Bedijing', 'Caidro','Amzstderdam', 'Washidnzgton', 'Sydzdney', 'Beijzding', 'Caidzro'],
        autoSelect: false,
        showHintOnFocus : true,
        minLength : 0
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the `Typeahead` plug-in , but in the second `bootstrap-tagsinput` plug-in. Unfortunately you can not solve it without editing the source.

Take a look to this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/ee9zrxnq/)

How you can read from source of the [bootstrap-tagsinput.js](https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js) at line 310:

```
sorter: function (texts) {
            return texts.sort();
          },
```

The `sorter` option is provided by the `bootstrap-tagsinput` plug-in to the `Typeahead` plug-in and since the plug-in is executed in a immediately invoked function expression you can't overwrite the `sorter` method.
You should fork the plug-in and change the sorter option:

```
sorter: function (texts) {

          var sorter = typeahead.sorter || function (items) { return items.sort(); }
          return sorter(texts);
        },
```

[image]

So your plugin initialization will be:

```
$('#ppp').tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
      source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo', 'Amstedrdam', 'Washidngton', 'Syddney', 'Bedijing', 'Caidro', 'Amzstderdam', 'Washidnzgton', 'Sydzdney', 'Beijzding', 'Caidzro'],
      sorter: function (texts) {
        return texts;
      }
    }
  });
```

...once you have done this then it will work

Comment: well. what if I don't need them to be sorted.

Comment: hey @prime don't you like the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

The library [provides a way](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead#options) to override the sorter. You could simply use that to override the default sorter and return the list as-is:

```
sorter: function (items) { 
           return items; 
        },
```

Also, [here](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/fc2d5dce4a5406d9b924224e395d5647918707c7/bootstrap3-typeahead.js#L272) is the default sorter implementation.